# row counter in mvc index view can't generate number

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to put a row counter in `index view` of my mvc project to count the items .my code is like this :

```
 @{ int a = 0; }
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @a=a+1;
        </td>
     </tr>
}
```

But the result is `0=a+1;`

Could you please give me some help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if you want to start counting rows from zero:

```
<td>@(a++)</td>
```

In case of counting from one, use preincrementation:

```
<td>@(++a)</td>
```

Comment: @MehrdadGhaffari actually, the right short-cut solution would be `@(++a)`, just for you to know. `a++` is not the same as `a=a+1`, these statements return different results.

Comment: @AgentFire - problem concerned the correct use of Razor syntax. Using pre or post increment is only a detail.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
@{ int a = 0; }
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @(a = a + 1);
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Or a shorter equivalent:

```
<td>@(++a)</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
<td>
  @a=a+1;
 </td>
```

to

```
<td>
  @(a=a+1)
</td>
```